# How to use dates in a sentence

Tags: nouns

In the following sentence

> [This has to change. Arab countries as well as the UN should put meaningful pressure on the military council to pay heed to popular demands and hold those responsible for the **June 3 massacre** accountable.](https://www.thehindu.com/opinion/editorial/sudan-on-the-brink/article27583356.ece)

It must be **June third massacre**. I am confused about how to use dates in a sentence somebody please help me

Comment: Even though it is not spelled “third” or “3rd” you still pronounce it “third”. This is a common way to write dates.

Comment: Why do you say it *must* be *June third*?

Comment: @Mixolydian I pronounce *June 3* as *June three*, and am used to others using that pronunciation when reading numerals in dates. (But regardless of pronunciation, the verbiage is still fine.)